# React-Native: Splash screen with resizable image (logo)

Tags: android, xml, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a simple splash screen where im setting the background color and add a image in the center, my problem is that the image its going out of the bounds and I am trying to find a way how to make it "responsive". Is there a good way how to do this with react-native/java?

What I have now:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:drawable="@color/green" />
      <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
      </item>
    </layer-list>

  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: have you placed the **logo** image for all resolution devices in drawable folder?

Comment: Isn't there another way how to do it? So for example to have one picture and to scale the size depending on the phone screen resolution?

Comment: if you scale one image for different resolution devices, it will may cause blurring your image on some devices.

Comment: Do you know all the resolutions precisely? And do you have a example how this works?

Comment: actually you have to make the images in ratio like 3:4:6:8:12 (m, h, xh, xxh, xxxh resp) e.g. if you are cutting a images with dimen like 12 * 12 which is for mdpi devices then for other devices you have to make images like 16 * 16 for hdpi, 24 * 24 for xhdpi resp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make different layouts for different devices.
I hope these Links will help you.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

http://www.android-examples.com/support-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android-responsive-example/